# Why android dialog.dismiss never called?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have implemented custom dialog in my app with accept and reject buttons. Unless the user clicks either of the buttons within 7 seconds the dismiss method gets fired. I want to dismiss the dialog if the user clicks any time within the 7 seconds but the dismiss method is never fired. I have searched all over SO but I haven't found a solution from the answers.

```
final Dialog d = new Dialog(MyActivity.this, R.style.Theme_Dialog);
d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
d.show();

spRequest.play(spSoundId, 1, 1, 1, 12, 1);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //dia.dismiss();
        d.dismiss();
    }
}, 7000);    //the alert will play for 7 seconds and stop

Button accept = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.acpt);
accept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        d.dismiss();
        spRequest.release();
    }
});

Button reject = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.rjct);
reject.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        d.dismiss();
        spRequest.release();
        msg.setText("");
    }
});
```

Update: after some debugging and research I noticed that if I click on the button twice, the dialog would be dismissed. I am guessing the dialog is drawn twice. I am still working on it. Like @aelimill said, this code works fine when called from the activity body(I tried it in OnCreate()) but the issue comes up when I execute it in a broadcast receiver.

Comment: I copied your code and it works flawlessly. Dialog got dismissed on button clicks. The only difference is this line spRequest.play(spSoundId, 1, 1, 1, 12, 1); (i commented it). Try to comment this line and the lines with spRequest.release() in buttons click listener

Comment: The dialog gets dismissed after 7 seconds. But if you click one of the buttons the d.dismiss is simply ignored. Have you clicked on the buttons?

Comment: Sorry, updated my comment :) Yes, the dialog got dismissed on button clicks

Comment: I appreciate your help. On mine the spRequest.release(); gets fired but the d.dismiss() is not. I will investigate more.

Comment: Try to wrap spRequest.release()  in try/catch in case of some uncatchable error

Comment: Did you see my update? Did you have to click your button twice?

Comment: No, i clicked one time to dismiss, so check you invokation method which shows the dialog :)

Comment: Well I am invoking it in a private broadcast receiver. I also moved it all to a new method and called that method from withing the broadcast receiver, but it behaves the same way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100719/discussion-between-aelimill-and-the-martian).

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you override the dialog buttons onClick methods to dismiss them, not buttons outside of the dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("MyMessage");

  alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        //do something
     }
  });

  alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        alertdialog.cancel();
        //or alertdialog.dismiss();
     }
  });

  AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
  alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But I believe implementing custom dialog is possible. I would like to consider the Android dialog as last option just because it looks ugly and not professional :(